# Probability for asymmetric random walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

[image: Following is probability chart for a asymmetric random walk. First row is the position label, first column is the time label.]

How to express this in equation form(in terms of position(x) and time(N)), like the one for symmetric random walk, 
$\displaystyle P(x,N) = \frac{N!}{(\frac{N+x}{2})! (\frac{N-x}{2})!}p^{\frac{N+x}{2}}q^{\frac{N-x}{2}}$

Also what will be the equation for a random walk with both absorbing and reflecting boundaries on each side(table 2, with absorbing boundary at 3).
[image: probability chart for random walk with absorbing and reflecting boundary.The walk will be absorbed at 3(variable)]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the equation you have is for asymmetric random walk with p being up probability and q being downward probability...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $\displaystyle2^{-n}\cdot{n\choose \frac{k+n}2}\cdot(1+\mathbf 1_{k\ne0})$, with the convention that $\displaystyle{n\choose i}=0$ when $i$ is not an integer.

Comment: thanks a lot. Could you please help me to find a similar equation for a table, that has "absorbing" point some where > 1. I have included that in my question.

Comment: Sorry but "both absorbing and reflecting boundaries" does not make much sense to me. Anyway, if you have a new question, the procedure is not to append it to a previous post but to post a new question.

Comment: my system works that way only. :( Sure will follow that from next time.